# Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask (state=08S01,code=1)

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have started metastore and hiveserver2

```
#./hive --service metastore
#./hive --service hiveserver2
```

When I excute below query

```
#./beeline -u jdbc:hive2://192.168.0.10:10000 -e 'select count(*) from test_tb'  --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console --verbose=true
```

It throws below error

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask (state=08S01,code=1)
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:275)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:736)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:657)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.dispatch(BeeLine.java:804)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.initArgs(BeeLine.java:608)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:630)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.mainWithInputRedirection(BeeLine.java:368)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.main(BeeLine.java:351)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Beeline version 0.13.1 by Apache Hive
```

hiveserver2 log below

```
6/06/14 10:57:32 [main]: WARN common.LogUtils: DEPRECATED: Ignoring hive-default.xml found on the CLASSPATH at /data/offline/apache-hive-0.13.1-bin/conf/hive-default.xml
16/06/14 10:57:32 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Starting hive metastore on port 9083
16/06/14 10:57:32 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
16/06/14 10:57:32 [main]: INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
16/06/14 10:57:33 [main]: INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
16/06/14 10:57:33 [main]: INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
16/06/14 10:57:34 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
16/06/14 10:57:34 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
16/06/14 10:57:34 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
16/06/14 10:57:34 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Starting DB backed MetaStore Server
16/06/14 10:57:34 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Started the new metaserver on port [9083]...
16/06/14 10:57:34 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Options.minWorkerThreads = 200
16/06/14 10:57:34 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Options.maxWorkerThreads = 100000
16/06/14 10:57:34 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: TCP keepalive = true
16/06/14 10:57:40 [pool-3-thread-1]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 1: source:/10.234.177.127 get_table : db=default tbl=test_tb
16/06/14 10:57:40 [pool-3-thread-1]: INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=qspace       ip=/10.234.177.127      cmd=source:/192.168.0.10 get_table : db=default tbl=test_tb
16/06/14 10:57:40 [pool-3-thread-1]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 1: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
16/06/14 10:57:40 [pool-3-thread-1]: INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
16/06/14 10:57:40 [pool-3-thread-1]: INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19097467/2308683

Comment: If you need, I will give more information

Comment: That would be great. It says execution failed for statement, but your statement looks fine

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, the link is helpless--- stackoverflow.com/a/19097467/2308683

Comment: Helpless or helpful?

Comment: @cricket_007  helpless

Comment: any updates on this issue. got same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Hiveserver2. For such aggregations, depending upon configuration, I believe you may need to set the number of reducers prior to execution. With Hive you can use this syntax:

```
SET mapred.reduce.tasks=1
```

However on Hive2 I have noticed I need to use:

```
SET mapreduce.job.reduces=1
```

I hope this helps! Previously I had a the same error message and changing this resolved the problem for me.

Comment: I tried, but it still throw the same error, still thanks

Answer (score 1):

This could be a permission issue,Try starting beeline as follows

> beeline
>
> !connect jdbc:hive2://hadoop7:10000/default

enter your user and password

Comment: was a permission issue for me! specifically i needed to use small letters in my user id as opposed to the actual caps in it. like remigiusz mentioned below it apparently works fine for select * queries, but fails for everything else

Answer (score 0):

Confirming that in my case it was caused by permission issue (as pointed already by wise_w) what was weird is that it looked like plain select * worked fine but anything more elaborate did not.

I tried the following:

```
$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://server1:10000
(connected fine, no errors)
> select * from table1;
-> worked fine

> select count(*) from table1;
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask (state=08S01,code=1)
or
ERROR : Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException(Permission denied: user=anonymous, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

The solution started with wise_w suggestion

```
$ beeline --incremental=true
$ !connect jdbc:hive2://server1:10000/default
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://server1:10000/default: hive
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://server1:10000/default: **** (this is hive as well in my test setup)
```

-> and now everything worked fine.

Now one liner

```
$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://server1:10000 -n hive -p hive --incremental=true
```

I thing the confision came from the fact, that connecting like:

```
$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://server1:10000
```

does not throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the below parameters, it is important in this case:

```
set mapred.job.queue.name=<your queue name>;
set mapreduce.job.reduces=1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the below snippet before running you your query:

```
SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 16384; 
SET mapreduce.map.java.opts='-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx13107M';
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb = 13107; 
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts='-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx16384M';
set hive.support.concurrency = false;
```